# Angular 2 | How to handle input type file in FormControl?

Tags: forms, angular

Good day,

How can i handle input type file in formControl? im using reactive form but when i get the value of my form it returns null value on my `<input type="file">`??

Comment: what do you expect to see there? and post your full code

Comment: the file path, so i can push it on my array, and store it on objects.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to write your own `FileInputValueAccessor`. Here is [the plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/gvq8z6Q6bnIGFSma56aH?p=preview) and the code:

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'input[type=file]',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: FileValueAccessorDirective,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class FileValueAccessorDirective implements ControlValueAccessor {
  onChange;

  @HostListener('change', ['$event.target.value']) _handleInput(event) {
    this.onChange(event);
  }

  constructor(private element: ElementRef, private render: Renderer2) {  }

  writeValue(value: any) {
    const normalizedValue = value == null ? '' : value;
    this.render.setProperty(this.element.nativeElement, 'value', normalizedValue);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn) {    this.onChange = fn;  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any) {  }

  nOnDestroy() {  }
}
```

And then you will be able to get updates like this:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
      <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
      <h3>File path is: {{path}}</h3>
      <input type="file" [formControl]="ctrl">
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  path = '';
  ctrl = new FormControl('');

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ctrl.valueChanges.subscribe((v) => {
      this.path = v;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Maximus, but how can i get the full path of the file? in your example you get the file path with `C:\fakepath\sample.xls` is their a way on getting the full path file? im trying to get the file path so i can send it on the server.

Comment: @JydonMah, what do you mean `full` file path? This is the absolute file path

Comment: just for example my file is located at 'C:\documents\sample.xls' it should return the `C:\documents\sample.xls` and not the `C:\fakepath\sample.xls`.

Comment: unfortunately, a browser doesn't expose that information because of security reasons. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav). The only thing you can get is `fileName`

Comment: Thanks Maximus for your example and info ;) finally understand it. many thanks.

Comment: @JydonMah, great, consider accepting or upvoting my answer then, thanks

Comment: @MaximKoretskyi I really liked your approach here. I've searched a lot until I finally found this reasonable solution. Would you mind to post it somewhere? Maybe on [**medium**](https://medium.com)? Also, a little question... doing this way, how can I display a thumbnail of the file? Could you expalin me or maybe add an example? Thanks.

Comment: @dev_054, yeah, I think I'll put up an article on medium soon. Regarding your question, can you please post a separate question and put the relevant details into the question details? You can then post a link to the question as a comment here

Comment: I'm getting error --- ERROR Error: More than one custom value accessor matches form control with unspecified name attribute

Answer (score 1):

there is no way to handle this in angular form-control.
we can provide some hack to make this work if you want to upload the image.
just add the `<input type=file>` as form control on which user can add the file and acter grabbing the file we can change it to the base64code and then assign that value to the hidden field of our main form.
then we can store the image file in that way.

else you can go for the ng-file-upload module[ng file upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload)

Comment: thanks for this advice, ill try to use local reference and pass value on it, but how can we get the full path of file after grabing that value? im getting fakepath everytime i get the value of input files

Comment: you can implement your own value accessor to specific input types, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45232279/2545680)

Comment: great solution we can go for this as well.